# Bundling performance inside ASP.NET MVC

Tags: cdn, bundling-and-minification, google-cdn

Is it better for performance to reference 4 js files on Microsoft CDN Example :
JQuery,
JQueryUI,
JQuery Validation,
Knockout.js
or have it all in one Bundle ?

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: Not really. There is a by default different bundle for each of these files. You can try to find file first on CDN and if this fails you can downgrade to your bundle then. Otherwise large number of users is using CDN so if you use CDN you have a great chance that you will already had that file cached in browser on client side so calling CDN will never be performed and you will get performance benefit there.

Comment: Happened on this and found more info in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445909/bundling-js-files-vs-cdn