# Bundling, RequireJS, and CDNs - Do they cancel each other out?

Tags: requirejs, cdn, bundling-and-minification

I know what you're all thinking, [can't he just use all 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445909/bundling-js-files-vs-cdn)? Yes, I could, but my question is this: do they not cancel each other out?

**tl;dr**

1. Does bundling make RequireJS obsolete?
2. Does bundling make CDNs obsolete?
3. If I have to make a choice between bundling or RequireJS+CDN, how do I determine which to use? Is it best practice to CDN common files, and bundle uncommon? What about SPA files?

**The long version**

For example, we bundle files for fewer HTTP requests. Whereas RequireJS is used so that files can be loaded dynamically and asynchronously, as they're needed.

*So if we bundle all our JS files into 1, is RequireJS even needed?*

Also, we use a CDN so the browser can access a cached version, so if the user visits 5 websites, all of which use a popular jQuery CDN - i.e. http://cdn.com/jquery.min.js - the browser actually needs to make no HTTP requests for this file on the last 4 sites, which is much faster than that file getting bundled. If those sites were to instead each access a unique bundled file from the CDN - specific to their needs - the odds of a cache "hit" become much lower. And, since the odds of a "hit" are lower, the file is less likely to be cached for even the people using that site.

*So does it really help for a bundled file to even be on a CDN?*

Answer (score 2):

> Whereas RequireJS is used so that files can be loaded dynamically and asynchronously, as they're needed.

Many developers use RequireJS to have a clean way to separate concerns *without* the need for loading modules dynamically. I have a few applications and libraries developed with RequireJS. One of them is a library that does not use the dynamic loading capabilities at all and would not benefit from using them. In almost all use-case scenarios for this library, it should be loaded as a single bundle, and not as a collection of modules, one-by-one.

This brings me to another thing: the decision is not **between** bundling **or** RequireJS. You can use `r.js` (RequireJS' optimizer) to bundle your RequireJS modules into a single file for production. This could include 3rd party modules if you want. Or you could leave them out to be served from a CDN. An application can be optimized to a single bundle, or a series of bundles. As any other optimization question, what should be done depends on the architecture of the specific application being considered.

The rest of your question is wholly opinion-based. I've seen detailed arguments supported by statistics that you should use a CDN, that you should not use a CDN, and everything in between. It is an optimization question, which, again, depends on the specifics of the application being considered.

Answer (score 0):

> So if we bundle all our JS files into 1, is RequireJS even needed?

Not all of it. You might be interested in [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond).

> A replacement AMD loader for RequireJS. It provides a minimal AMD API footprint that includes loader plugin support. Only useful for built/bundled AMD modules, does not do dynamic loading.